# Is there a way to programmatically get a shareable link for google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-forms

Is there a way to programmatically get a shareable link for google form?
I've copied a google form file using php api and now I want to get a sharable link to this form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shareable URL of a Google Form is of the form

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{id}/viewform
```

where `id` is the Id associated with the file containing the form. Since you have made a copy of the file, you have a corresponding File object, so use the method for getting its id, and include it in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

If you already was able to get the form you alread have the form id and you could build the URL that you need.

## Explanation

There are two basic Google Forms URLs:

- one to edit the form
- another to view the live form and submit a response.

The difference between them is that the first includes /edit while the other includes instead /viewform

`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1os2J7uSWpBYDvbFViL1cmMaIPXD1QDGSwiWfODiKINU/edit`

`1os2J7uSWpBYDvbFViL1cmMaIPXD1QDGSwiWfODiKINU` is the file id.

Anyway, you could use Google Apps Script to get those URLs but first you should get a form object. If you are using Google Apps Script bounded project to a spreadsheet or to a form, first you should get the active spreadsheet/form then use the corresponding method.

Also you could use Google Drive REST API to get the file id that correspond to the form.

If you already have a Google Form URL it contains the form id. You use the URL or the form id it to open the form and then get the URL that you need, but this could

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get the form attached to given sheet:

```
function getFormUrl(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet.getFormUrl();
}
```